# FAST For SharePoint Web Crawler Meta Tag Extraction

Tags: sharepoint-2010, meta-tags, fast-esp, fastsearch

I am using FAST For SharePoint to crawl a non SharepPoint website. The website crawled with no error, I can get the results of any keyword.

I want to create refiner on result page by html page meta tags. There must be two level refiner; category and sub category. If user clicks category, refiner panel must show all related sub categories.

The meta tags like this:

```
<meta name="Category" content="Products"/>
<meta name="SubCategory" content="Electronic"/>
```

**How can I extract meta tags that crawled html page(s) with FAST For SharePoint Webcrawler?**

I tried to add the meta tag names to *FAST Search Administration > Managed Properties* and configured refiner panel for those meta tags, but I could not get result. It does not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom Managed Property, you need to first bind them to a crawled property. Crawled properties are created automatically during the crawl, or you can create them in powershell, see the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ff393776(v=office.14).aspx

If I understand well, what you are trying to do is getting information that is in the HTML of your page. In this case, you cannot use the out-of-the-box web crawler to get this information. I suggest you take a look on custom BDC connector, if you want to create a custom crawler to get the information you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557349(v=office.14).aspx